# matched count for characters in two variables

Tags: regex, perl, count

Iam trying to match two variables and get the count of characters that are matched.

For ex:

```
$name1 = 'cat';

$name2 = 'dcat';
```

**result needs to be 3.**

Tried this but always prints 1

```
$count = 0;
$count++ while ($name1 =~ /$name2/g);
print "$count\n";
```

Comment: Is order important? ie. is the result with `cat` the same than with `tac`?

Comment: yes order is important

Comment: So, must the result with `cat` be the same than with tac? Please update your question to take this into account, add some sample strings an expected result.

Comment: Are you asking for the length of the [Longest Common Substring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem)

Comment: What is the answer you seek if you have `$name1 = 'tac';` and `$name2 = 'dcat';`? ie, are you looking for the length of the substring or the count of the characters contained? What about multiple character matches?

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = 0;
$matchstr = "";
foreach (split(//,$name1)){
    $matchstr .= $_;
    $count++ if $name2 =~ /$matchstr/;
}
print "No of matched characters are: $count \n ";
```

Comment: Using this way you can match the characters keeping order.